# How do I convert a large edgelist csv to an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I have a large [edge list](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/datasets/Flixster) of 2M nodes that I am trying to convert to an adjacency matrix. The code that I previously used to change edgelists to adjacency matrices does not work on this dataset because it is too large. Are there any other links or methods I could use?

Comment: What's too large?  The edge_list or the resulting adjacency matrix?

Comment: Without knowing about your previous code and where it breaks down, it's difficult to make suggestions.  So it would help to see some of your code.  My best guess is that the problem is the adjacency matrix is too big.  In that case, try using a sparse matrix (which in the underlying data structure is pretty much treated like an edge list)

Comment: the edge list @hpaulj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a sparse matrix.

With [`nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html) you can convert a graph to a sparse adjacency matrix.

Comment: I have turned it to a sparse matrix. Is there a way to convert from sparse to adjacency?

Comment: You can try calling `to_dense`, but maybe you get an out of memory error.

Comment: yes that was the solution! Thank you so much. After turning it todense I just turned it into a pandas dataframe for aesthetics @Sparky05

Comment: Yes, but this presumes that you are able to create a networkx graph which will consume lot more ram than a scipy sparse matrix...